# SQL Server Coding questions [multiple columns in the same line]

Tags: sql-server

I am going through SQL server code and want to understand what does this line of code in the select statement means.

```
othertable.othercolumnname

--The following line I don't understand
,[ge_oktouse].[ufn_getAgreedState](AG.AgreedIssuedDate, AG.AgreedExpiryDate, AG.AgreedReceivedDate) AS 'Agreed State'

,othertable2.othercolumnname2
Where AG = table called [ge_oktouse].[AgreedRequests]
```

Comment: Please can you provide the whole statement.

Comment: `[ge_oktouse].[ufn_getAgreedState]` is a user defined (scalar) function that has the parameters in the parenthesis passed to it. What that function *does*, however, we don't know.

Comment: That line of code invokes a scalar valued function. The column values in parenthesis are function parameters.

Comment: Thanks.I think I found the answer :)